# Symfony security firewall and access control rule for either an authenticated user or a trusted IP address

Tags: php, security, symfony

I would like to restrict access to certain resources to either authenticated users or clients from trusted IP addresses. Is there an out of the box solution for this or do I need to create a custom Voter for this...?

Answer (score 2):

Into your `security.yml` file

```
security:
 #...
 access_control:
  - { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

You could also secure the entire application, by add some controls into `app.php` file, but I suppose that this isn't what you need